# Chart.js - x-axis and tooltip label shows "undefined" in Chrome when browser language is NOT English

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an issue with Chart.js on my website. The chart is showing properly when the app language in Chrome is set to English, but when I change my browser language to another language, for example Norwegian, both the x-axis and tooltip label shows `undefined` instead of correct date.

You can see preview page here: https://coinpanda.tax/price/bitcoin/

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

**Graph not showing correctly:**
[image: Graph not showing correctly]

**Graph showing correctly:**
[image: Graph showing correctly]

Comment: What is the your version chart.js? and can you add the code of your canvas tag?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly related to how you've included Chart.js in your web page. Since Chart.js is [dependent upon moment.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-formats) for time axes you need to ensure moment.js [includes all the locales](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) you want to support.

- If you're using the [Chart.js bundled build](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) (which includes moment.js) then you'll need to switch to the non-bundled build and include moment.js+locales separately.
- If you're already using the [stand-alone build](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#stand-alone-build) then you need to add the relevant locales.